# iOS CoreBluetooth: How long does it remain in background? (At least...)

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Could CoreBluetooth on background **remain over 5 minutes?**

I'm making an social alarm application. So I need to alarm others in 5 minutes after connecting bluetooth. Here's my scenario.

> 9:55 Embedded system alarm: "Turn on your app please!" then user turn on bluetooth once.
>   10:00 Bluetooth is activated with others on background with both central and peripheral.

In reference, the exact time isn't stated clearly. It says just "Even if your app supports one or both of the Core Bluetooth background execution modes, it can’t run forever." Are there anyone who has an experience about this? I need any help.

Comment: It really depends on what else is happening on the phone. Generally you can expect your app to run in the background for several hours or even days, but if a particularly memory intensive app is loaded then your app may get terminated straight away.  If you implement state restoration then iOS will relaunch your app when the peripheral comes into range even if it has been terminated

Comment: You help me again this time. I'm so thank you. Have a nice day~! @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11 My understanding of docs is different then yours. IMHO `background state` is only transitional state. If you are using `Background execution`, app stay in background only for few seconds (some say max 15 sec) then app transitioning to `suspended state`. Due to memory pressure app can be purged from suspended state without warning. When BTLE restoration occurs system wakes app from suspended to background (or launch if previously purged) for few seconds to execute background task then app returns to suspended state. I don't think app can **run** in background for a hours/days.

Comment: I guess it depends on what was meant by "run". I interpreted it to mean "be able to respond to Bluetooth events ". If the question referred to actively execute code then no, it can't.

Comment: It's not easy to ask a question with short knowledge... I'm sorry. I don't need "run". I just need to be able to respond to Bluetooth events then user can get any notification. Thanks for your careful concern, @psci